# Is there a way to require a module in TypeScript without binding a new variable?

Tags: typescript

The standard module import syntax in TypeScript,

```
import foo = require('foo');
```

requires you to bind a new identifier to the imported module. But in some cases I just want to express a dependency without binding anything. For example, if I'm depending on a jQuery plugin that doesn't actually export things, it just adds new fields to jQuery itself. Is there a way to do something like

```
require('foo');
```

without the import part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the undocumented `amd-dependency` flag :

```
/// <amd-dependency path="foo"/>
```

Additional information (slightly dated video) : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4AGQpv0MKsA&hd=1

Comment: thanks for your help, here's my latest TypeScript question if you're interested: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20140752/developing-a-requirejs-exported-library-in-typescript