# Developing a requirejs-exported library in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Apologies if this question is a bit unfocused/rambling, but what I really have here are several interrelated questions that I'd like to ask all at once.

Suppose I'm developing a library called `foo` which consists of files `foo.ts`, `bar.ts` and `baz.ts`. `foo.ts` is the root of the library, i.e. it depends on the other two and exports all the functionality that might be needed by a dependent application. Suppose also that I want to make this library available as an AMD-loadable module.

What is the right way to structure this code in TypeScript? Here are the ways that I can think of to do this:

1. Use `/// <reference path="..."/>` throughout the files, and then use `--out combined.js` to combine them into one big library. But if I do this, I don't see how to make the combined output available downstream as an AMD module. If I add an `export` statement to the `foo` module, it has no effect on the combined file, only producing a requirejs-wrapped version of `foo.js`. So it seems that combining internal modules via `--out combined.js` and then making certain parts of the combined result available via an `export` is not straightforward. Should I just use another tool to wrap the concatenated result in AMD boilerplate, eschewing the `import`/`export` features of TypeScript?
2. Make `foo.ts`, `bar.ts` and `baz.ts` all external modules, have them depend on one another using e.g. `import bar = require('./bar');`, and have `foo.ts` export a module containing only the parts of `bar` and `baz` that are part of the library's public API. If I go this route, then by default, since we're using AMD modules, all files will be downloaded separately, even though they're highly inter-dependent, which seems less than ideal. But I could use the requirejs optimizer to combine the resulting individual modules into one big module. However, if the application using the library is also written in TypeScript and wants to make use of its declarations, where should it look? When using the `--out combined.js` option as in (1), it's possible to also get a combined `.d.ts` for the library, but when using external modules I don't see how to do this. Should the downstream application code instead reach into the source directory and pick up individual declaration files, i.e. `foo.d.ts`, `bar.d.ts`, `baz.d.ts`? Should I manually create a master declaration file that refers to all the auto-generated singleton `.d.ts`s?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do. Compile with `--out lib.js --declaration` flags all files except `foo.ts`. And then use the declaration to create `foo.ts` e.g. Assume:

`bar.ts`:

```
module Foo{
   export class Bar{
   }
}
```

`baz.ts`:

```
module Foo{
   export class Baz{
   }
}
```

The declaration file (due to `--declaration` flag) you will get is :

```
module Foo{
  export class Bar{
   }
  export class Baz{
   }
}
```

So you can create `Foo.ts` as :

```
/// <reference path="lib.d.ts"/>
declare module "Foo"{
  export = Foo;
}
```

Then hardcode a `lib.dist.js` to load the --out js file and export to amd:

```
define([require,'lib'],function(){
    return Foo;
});
```

**UPDATE**
If you need to depend on a third party lib use `<amd-depenedency` in `Foo.ts` and use `Foo.ts` yourself as well in other sections.

Comment: Two questions: 1) I'm not sure I understand the point of the the `Foo.ts` file as you've described it... doesn't the `lib.d.ts` file already accomplish that? 2) How does `lib.dist.js` "load" the --out js file? The `lib.js` file itself has to be wrapped in requirejs boilerplate somehow. I can use the `grunt-requirejs` task to do that, but a side affect of all this is that source maps no longer work :(

Comment: I could also treat `lib.js` as a legacy library with a global constant and export it with a shim, but that's pretty unfortunate too since it puts the onus on the consumer of the library.

Comment: Ah, I see the point of `Foo.ts`, to make an external module for downstream typescript code to import.

Comment: Ah, I see the point of Foo.ts, to make an external module for downstream typescript code to import. : yes

Comment: Ok, I think I understand your solution, and it works as long as my library doesn't have its own AMD dependencies. But suppose my library needs JQuery... how could I represent that dependency? I don't see a way to do it without forcing the consumer of the library to write a shim for it.

Comment: adding `<amd-dependency ...>` tags only affect the generated code for external modules, which `Foo.ts` is not currently. Are you suggesting making it an external module and `import`ing it everywhere?

Comment: I ended up going with the "AMD-ify everything" route, and then optimizing the resulting multitude of modules to a `.min` file. I lose TS source maps that way, but the requirejs optimizer does produce JS source maps so it's not too bad. Also I can easily switch my requirejs config to use the unoptimized JS, in which case I get TS source maps. There's an [open issue](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/issues/470) on requirejs to support input source maps, which would make even that compromise unnecessary.

Comment: @TomCrockett - did you manage to get type definitions for your library working in your consuming project? I'm trying to solve a similar problem to you and I've gone down the RequireJS + optimiser route - however I can't get my consuming project to understand the typings of my library.

Answer (score 1):

New way! Forget the references, just put a tsconfig.json file at the root of the project, and all will work with no collisions.